# jQuery statements which interact with the DOM not working on 'soft' refresh only, but console log statements are

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like I am banging my head against a wall right now; I know it has been reported, in jQuery 1.8.0, that the `document.ready` function is firing too early in IE 9 & 10. However I have the following snippet of code running under jQuery latest (1.9.1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.ie = (function(){
            var undef, v = 3, x = 9, div = document.createElement('div'), div2 = document.createElement("div"), all = div.getElementsByTagName('i'), bs = div2.getElementsByTagName("b");
            while ( div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->', all[0] );
            while ( div2.innerHTML = '<!--[if lte IE ' + x + ']><b></b><![endif]-->', bs[0] ) {
                $("body").addClass("lteie" + x--);
            }
            if(v > 4) $("body").addClass("isie" + v);
            return v > 4 ? v : undef;
        }());
    });
</script>
```

This works when I refresh from server but it is not working when I use `ctrl + R` or `f5`. I am running this app locally. Not sure if this is important but I have tried setting it to always refresh from server via dev tools, refreshed once with success and then disabled this setting and it still doesn't run this script fully - it seems that if I put an alert in there, or console.log, it works fine (doesn't add the classes but does alert or write to the console even when put *within* the while loop). If it refreshes from server or using `ctrl + f5`, surely the cached copy should be replaced, right?

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Richard

Comment: Note that I have thought about the possibility that another script is, for some reason, removing these classes - but if that was the case then this script wouldn't work on hard refresh either. It seems to work on hard refresh but not soft.